# Getting 'undefined' when trying to get value from Parsed xhr.responseText

Tags: javascript, json, django

I have this javascript function where it makes a GET request to my Django server and get a JSON response but when i try to get the values from the json after parsing xhr.responseText with JSON.parse(), I get 'undefined'. What and Where am I doing it wrong?

```
function getSignedRequest(file){
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', `/sign-s3?file-name=${file.name}&file-type=${file.type}`);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if(xhr.readyState === 4){
      if(xhr.status === 200){
        const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        //var apple = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        alert(response.url); //gives undefined
        console.log(response);
        //uploadFile(file, response.data, response.url);
      }
      else{
        alert('Could not get signed URL.');
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

This the JSON data i get after parsing it. It is a valid json.

```
{"url": "https://myurlfromserver", "data":      {"url": "https://myurlfromserver", "fields": {"myremainimg data"}}}
```

Comment: what happens in the console when you do `console.log(response);`?

Comment: data as currently written is not valid JSON: `"fields": {"myremainimg data"}`

Comment: After parsing, the data should no longer be a JSON string, but your last line looks like it's probably a string.

Comment: @I wrestled a bear once It gives something like what i posted at the end, off course I removed some imported data from the "fields" but it was a valid JSON which I validated from https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: `{"url": "https://myurl", "data": {"url": "https://myurl", "fields": {"AWSAccessKeyId": "accesskey", "acl": "public-read", "key": "image.jpg", "signature": "signature", "policy": "mypolicy", "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"}}}`  my actual response when console logged.

Comment: @pavitran: Are you saying that's the value of the `response` variable? Or are you saying it's the actual response given in `xhr.responseText`? It's unclear which `console.log()` you're referring to.

Comment: @squint that's the value of `response` when I do `console.log(response);` but when I tried `alert(response.url);` It gave me `undefined`. I'm in a tight schedule for my project would be very thankful if somebody could help!

Comment: I don't know why but when I did `JSON.parse(response)` again, it worked! "My code doesn't work, I don't why. My code works, I don't know why"